# Xamarin forms, Pull to refresh listView in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

How to refresh a list with Xamarin forms when running on Windows desktop?
It seems we can't pull to refresh.
Tks.

François

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pull to refresh in a ListView on Xamarin Forms requires you to implement these 3 things.

```
IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshListCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
```

If you have those 3 things, PullToRefresh will work.

However I have been looking at the code for UWP and can not find anywhere how Xamarin Forms implements PullToRefresh for either WinRT or UWP. Looking at the documentation, WinRT is not supported and hence I assume UWP also wouldn't be supported at this time.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Pull_to_Refresh

Only WP8SL, iOS and Android have PullToRefresh supported at this moment in time.

Comment: That's what I thought as well 

Comment: @adam-pedley Hi i am trying to implement PullToRefresh  in xamarin UWP and is not working. Is this still not supported? Is there any alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Worked for me.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" />
```

Set IsPullToRefreshEnabled=”True” to enable the functionality, then create these 2 properties in your ViewModel.

```
private bool _isRefreshing = false;
public bool IsRefreshing { 
get { return _isRefreshing; }
set {
    _isRefreshing = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
    }
}

public ICommand RefreshCommand
{
    get {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;

            await RefreshData();

            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Now when you pull down from the top of the listview, it will show a refresh animation, while `IsRefreshing=”true”.`

Example

[image: Example]