# Why doesn’t my Xamarin.Forms UWP’s ListView provide the “pull to scroll” behaviour?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, pull-to-refresh

I’m building a Xamarin.Forms UWP application, in which I provide a `ListView` populated from the code-behind of the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ...>
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <ListView IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The bind works just fine, but the problem is that I don’t understand why I’m not able to pull to refresh the list. The list is just static; I can only scroll up or down using the mouse's wheel or the scrollbar. The code-behind of the page is this:

```
public partial class MainPage {
   public MainPage() {
      BindingContext = this;
      Items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi" };
      
      RefreshCommand = new Command(async () => {
                IsRefreshing = true;
                await RefreshData();
                IsRefreshing = false;
      });

      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private bool _isRefreshing = false;
   public bool IsRefreshing {
      get { return _isRefreshing; }
      set {
         _isRefreshing = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
      }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }

    private async Task RefreshData() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Can you help me spot the problem?

Comment: you are right
> Users have come to expect that pulling down on a list of data will refresh that list. The ListView control supports this out-of-the-box. To enable pull-to-refresh functionality, set IsPullToRefreshEnabled to true:

Comment: As you can read in my post, I already put the `IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"` stuff in my XAML, but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: does anything happen when you pull from top or nothing?

Comment: @Cfun no, nothing. I can only scroll using the scrollbar.

Comment: if there is no activity indicator appearing it could be a bug

Comment: Hi, it seems UWP not supports this, have a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496699/xamarin-forms-pull-to-refresh-listview-in-uwp You also could submit an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) in Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PullToRefresh isn't implemented in the UWP version of [ListViewRender.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/80a4dbfb1cd897f478c38d0aafa6a5d67940d2f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ListViewRenderer.cs) . If you search the Xamarin.Forms source for IsPullToRefreshEnabled you'll find it only in the iOS and Android implementations of ListViewRenderer.

This was discussed in the following bug report with the current recommendation to use [RefreshView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/refreshview) :

[PullTORefresh is not working for the UWP platform using XamarinForms ListVIew](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2086)

> Please try the RefreshView instead. Thanks!